# Get all plain text with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I can get all code of page with Puppeteer, but how I can get only the plain text? without tags?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com');
  console.log(await page.content()); //Get all code
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tried it, but [`$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) might work for you:

```
await page.$eval('*', el => el.innerText);
```

Comment: Pardon my complete ignorance as far as programming in JS: how can I save the result to a file or display in the node.js console?

Comment: This would show the result in the console - `const text = await page.$eval('*', el => el.innerText); console.log(text);`.

Answer (score 3):

guys. I've gathered few possible variants in my article:
[How to get all text from a webpage using Puppeteer?](https://scrapingant.com/blog/puppeteer-get-all-text)

To keep things short:

1. `innerText` variant. Works with most webpages, but not all of them

```js
await page.$eval('*', el => el.innerText);
```

2. Select text variant. Works with more webpages

```js
await page.$eval('*', (el) => {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(el);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    });
```

3. Use a third-party library of your choice (like [`html-to-text`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text))